# How to find Currents based on mesh analysis?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

[image]

Can anyone explain or give an example as to how to solve these three currents? I have tried very hard, but I keep getting stuck and obtaining the wrong answers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_circuit_laws

Comment: Well if you could show us where you are getting things wrong, then you may have a conceptual misunderstanding. We can’t help if we don’t know what you’re having problems with.